# UIView Draw method called multiple times on animating the sublayer

Tags: animation, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, cashapelayer

I have sub classed the UIView and added the sublayer(inherited from CAShape layer) to this class and I am animating the sublayer in the draw method of UIView.

While animating before the animation gets completed, draw method called multiple times and this results in flicker. This issue occurs while navigating the page and occurs only in iOS12. I am using CADisplaylink for animation.

Inside the draw method I am using the following code to perform animation

```
            if (myCAShapeLayer == null)
                myCAShapeLayer = new AnimationLayer(this); // animation layer inherited from CAShapeLayer.


            this.Layer.AddSublayer(myCAShapeLayer);

            Animate(); //Animation logics.

            myCAShapeLayer.StrokeColor = RangeColor.CGColor; //set to some color
            myCAShapeLayer.FillColor = RangeColor.CGColor; // set to some color
```

Comment: You can show some code about `OnDraw()` method ,is this just happen in ios12 not before version?

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I have included codes used inside draw. If I include these set of codes in the layout subview method instead of Draw, it is working properly. Is this the right way to work it out?

Comment: Ok, you can set the property of the view is `IsOpaque = false`,If if work,please tell me .I will explain this for answer.

Comment: I have already set Opaque false for my UIView. When I moved my animation logics to LayoutSubView, it works but dynamic update of the value is not working. Since on dynamic update only draw method gets hit.

Comment: Ok,so it is not my thinked.You can try to add this `this.Layer.AddSublayer(myCAShapeLayer);` to view's init method,not add in draw method.Problem should be to write the inappropriate code in the draw method.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT I have solved this issue (animating twice) by checking the condition whether animation has completed or not. This solution works fine when I set background but this gets failed when background is not set. But I cannot figure out the reason for Draw method calling multiple times. When background is not set Draw method called more number of times compared to when background set. Can you share your ideas on this?